# Get radius from a circle to screen corners

Tags: java, android, math, trigonometry

I followed an online tutorial, I did not understand how the professor managed to get the distance of a circle from the top left corner of the screen:

```
//calculate the distance from epicenter (of a circle) to the top left corner of the screen

double theta = atan(epicenter.dy/epicenter.dx);
double distanceToCorner = epicenter.dy / sin(theta);
```

**I would like to know how to get the distance from all the other screen corners** (and possibly have an explanation of what has been done).

Thank you

Comment: sin(c) = perpendicular / hypotenuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, that in android you can get screen width and height, you can simply count the distance at horizontal and vertical axis separately. 
Getting the distances at those axes, you can use Pythagoras equation, like

```
dist = sqrt( dx^2 * dy^2 )
```

To make it more felxible, just make a function, that takes corner position as a parameter and make the **dx** and **dy** as a absolute difference of corner and epicenter location.

Going back to your question and **atan(...)**, I don't quite understand the need of using this here, except if that's a project for the math class :)

Comment: Great, I was focused on the example that I did not think to solve it with the Pythagorean theorem, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer but if i understand what you mean, then this image might be helpful.

[image]